# Parse.com Cloud Code afterSave( ) Error: "Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object."

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, after-save

**Context**

I am using **Parse.com** after my backend for a web application.  The problem I am having relates to **Cloud Code**.

After a user completes their profile, I want to call an *afterSave( )* function which *updates* a few fields in the dataset MY_TABLE.

The fields being updated (variable01, variable02, and variable03) are retrieved via the function MY_FUNCTION with inputs param01 and param02.

**Error**

I get the following error, which I cannot fix: **"Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object."**

**Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("PROFILE_COMPLETE", function(request) {
    // Use Master Key
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    // Identify Parameters in Request
    var param01 = request.user.get('param01');
    var param02 = request.user.get('param02');

    // Print Parameters to Console
    console.log("Parameter 01 (" + param01 + ") successfully identified");
    console.log("Parameter 02 (" + param02 + ") successfully identified");

    // Identify Variables by Calling MY_FUNCTION()
    Parse.Cloud.run('MY_FUNCTION', {param01: param01, param02: param02}, {
        success: function(results) {
            // Print Results
            console.log("Function MY_FUNCTION() returned successful response");
            console.log(results);

            // Print Result Variables
            console.log("Identified variable01 = " + results.variable01);
            console.log("Identified variable02 = " + results.variable02);
            console.log("Identified variable03 = " + results.variable03);

            // Do I need to extend MY_TABLE or something else here???
            // I am doing the update and save wrong...

            // Update 'Complete' Data
            request.object.set("variable01", results.variable01);
            request.object.set("variable02", results.variable02);
            request.object.set("variable03", results.variable03);

            // Save Variables to 'MY_TABLE'
            request.object.save(null, {
                success: function(results) {
                    console.log("Variables successfully updated in MY_TABLE dataset");
                    console.log(results);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("Error when saving variables in MY_TABLE dataset");
                    console.log("Error " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
                }
            })
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("There was an error when running function MY_FUNCTION()");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `request.object.save`, just `response.success`.

Comment: **Parse.Cloud.afterSave( )** does not have a "response" called as part of the function syntax: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably missing some information in your description but I hope my previous experience can help:

Last time I got this error, I was doing the following:

context: inside a query callback where the result variable is `res`

```
var MyParseClass = Parse.Object.extend("MyParseClass");
var newObject = new MyParseClass();

res.set("pointerFieldToMyParseClass",newObject);

res.save();
```

In this example, `newObject` doesn't have an existence outside the scope of this function, so you must save it first:

```
var MyParseClass = Parse.Object.extend("MyParseClass");
var newObject = new MyParseClass();

newObject.save({
   success:function(savedObject){

      res.set("pointerFieldToMyParseClass",newObject);
      res.save();

   },error:function(e){}});
```